# Unable to pass Event data to Api.ai

Tags: python, python-3.x, dialogflow-es

I am trying to raise Event to Api.ai and pass data in python client

```
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
parm = {}
parm['amount'] = 222
parm['CName'] = 'CustName'

event1 = apiai.events.Event("MyCustomEvent")
event1.data = parm
request = ai.event_request(event1)
```

MyCustomEvent is defined and linked to right intent.
Intent has mandatory parameters defined CName and amount

The event and intent gets triggered on sending the request.
But data does not get mapped

What am i doing wrong? can someone please help
Or point me to some sample to get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky and it's something I've discovered while working with API.ai. As far as I can tell, API.ai has a lot of "undocumented features", this being one of them.

You can actually set parameters when you trigger an event, UNLESS the event you're trying to trigger has the same parameters as the one you're passing to that intent when triggering. What happens then is the following: API.ai will mysteriously and magically "blank" out those parameters, as if they're being reset by the intent.

I've posted on the API.ai forums about this, if it's an actual feature or a bug, but I haven't gotten any response about it thus far.

So to give you a concrete example, let's say we have:

```
Intent: "customIntent"
Entity: "amount"
Entity: "cname"
Event: "myCustomEvent"
ContextIn: "testIn"
ContextOut: "testOut"
```

if I trigger this intent with an event from the webhook containing the following JSON:

```
{
  "followupEvent": {
    "name": "myCustomEvent",
    "data": {
      "amount": "2222",
      "Cname": "a persons name",
      "testentity": "this shouldn't be blank"
    }
  }
}
```

amount and Cname will be blank and reset by the intent, you can look up the context in the API.ai console to see this result, however, testentity won't be blank and reset since testentity isn't in the intent's param list.

It's weird and confusing but that's what happened through multiple tests I ran. In order to solve this issue I've created a workaround by making an additional intent with the same "user sentences" and contextin and contextout as the intent I've tried to trigger in the first place but with the difference of not adding any parameters to this new intent.

It looks something like this:

```
Intent: "customIntent"
Entity: "amount"
Entity: "cname"
ContextIn: "testIn"
ContextOut: "testOut"

Intent: "workaroundIntent"
Event: "myCustomEvent"
ContextIn: "testIn"
ContextOut: "testOut"
```

That's how I solved this myself, as to why this happens, I'm still waiting for that response myself by one of the API.ai staff members.

Comment: Apologies for late response, actually missed your reply earlier. Thanks for great explanation, had not been able to figure out the behaviour. Will try your solution. Have put in an inefficient workaround meanwhile.